# How to choose the best type of vegan protein to take?

Tags: running, protein

I am man! I have been running and I would like to add to my diet some protein bars or powder [vegetable] protein.

Since I am intolerant to milk and I can only consider the vegan ones.

However, I have realized that some of them contains soy protein (is it bad?) and a large amount of sodium? 1) Should I avoid these ones? Or soy protein is ok? 2) How about sodium? What is an acceptable amount of sodium?

3) The one presented below is acceptable?

[image]

4) What are the best proteins for the ones that cannot drink milk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience as a vegan trying to gain muscle mass, I don't recommend protein powder. It's expensive and frankly not worth it. You can do the same by eating right and healthy, and working out properly.

However, there are many great alternatives to it! Obviously, you should never consume extreme quantities of anything, and it is generally healthier to have many sources of protein.

My personal favorite is a meal of beans and rice. Beans are filled with protein (35-45 grams per cup), and can be made into lots of different foods (Bean burgers, re-fried beans, steamed green/string beans, etc).

Nuts and seeds are also great. I am quite attached to sun flour seeds and chia seeds. Sunflour seeds are great in salads or plain, and you can get them toasted or raw, salted or unsalted. Chia seeds also have lots of protein (57.8 grams per cup), and can be great. Grind them up and add them to milk overnight for a great pudding, add chia seed powder to soups or other dishes for thickener.

I also happen to love [TVP](http://www.swansonvitamins.com/bobs-red-mill-tvp-textured-vegetable-protein-10-oz-pkg?SourceCode=INTL405C&CAWELAID=558417630&catargetid=530002460000120888&cadevice=c&mkwid=n7yGusgM&pcrid=80480719327&gclid=CjwKEAjw5vu8BRC8rIGNrqbPuSESJADG8RV0JpQeYmeSrrddryKymRWcuju89x5A8aQSgzZsQh_TTxoCIm3w_wcB) (Textured Vegetable Protein). Its very filling, very high in protein, and you can add it to sauces, or add hot water and eat it alone. Its just great. Plenty of protein, fiber and potassium.

If you're into that kind of stuff, bugs are also pretty great. I read an article about the UN encouraging people to consume bugs. They have lots of protein and nutrients. [UN Article](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-22508439)

As of 2013, the general guideline for the average male under 51 (above is 1,500 mg) is to consume no more than 2,300 mg of sodium per day, but far less is advised. Unsalted sunflour seeds have next to no sodium, and the same goes for chia seeds and most nuts (unless you buy salted). Beans have sodium, but if you cook/soak your own beans overnight, you can control the sodium level and keep it to a minimum. The specific brand of Vegetable Protein I mentioned above has just 2 mg of sodium per serving.

Typically for me, I eat lunch (Usually beans, whole wheat tortilla, feta cheese [has 21 grams protein serving], salsa, in-season fruit), go workout (at the moment for me, this means swimming for an hour or so and biking a few miles), then I like to get more protein in some way, whether it's downing a cup of sun flour seeds, or eating a handful of nuts. I dropped from 170 to 165 eating like this, and I put on easily 5 lbs muscle.

Another favorite of mine is to make my own protein/snack bars. I just pull out the food processor, and add some dried fruit and nuts. Usually I use almonds and walnuts. For fruit, I use dried figs, dates, cranberries, raisins and cherries (Lots of fiber, and energy from sugar). I just pulse it all together until it combines, then I pack the mixture into 1/4 cup measure cups and wrap them individually in wax paper for storage in the fridge.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There is no "best type" unless we know significantly more about you, and what you're trying to accomplish.

Anything on the shelf in a store is approved by higher powers, and won't do you any immediate harm unless you're allergic or otherwise intolerant to one or more of the ingredients.

> Or soy protein is ok?
>
> The one presented below is acceptable?

Yes and yes.

And no, there can be no more detailed answer, because there is no detail in the question. It's like asking "is bread ok?"

> What are the best proteins for the ones that cannot drink milk?

That depends on factors that you aren't giving us. Your goals, your weight, your workout regimen etc.

Comment: My worries were related to the fact that I read somewhere about the high amount of sodium and the usage of soy protein   that is related to the risk of cancer (?) in protein powder or bars. It is not clear what is considered a high amount of sodium that can affect the body pressure or the (danger) effects of soy protein or other proteins.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan Sodium content is still a controversial topic: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/comments/4voch4/what_are_some_dietary_myths_that_many_people_dont/d60flh6

Comment: The recommended daily sodium intake on a 2.5k cal diet is 1.5g. More if you are very active and sweat a lot. Most westerners far exceed this guideline thus greatly increasing their risk of heart attack, among other risk factors. I am not aware of a cancer risk from sodium. Regarding cancer and soy, the problem is most likely how the soy is processed rather than the soy itself, although I have no source here. That said, soy is often GMO and tends to cause sensitivities in susceptible people when consumed excessively.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but I know:
  - Soy is good.
  - It will be great you don't consume more than 1,500 milligrams of sodium per day (in all your diet).
  - The best proteins are not industrials. It is better if you eat lentils or peas (it's an example) to get your protein.